# How to pre-train the unified language model (UniLm)

Tags: python, nlp, transfer-learning, bert-language-model, nlg

I'm working on a non-English `NLP` project and for that, I need to re-train the `UniLm` on the `bert-base-multilingual-cased`, but they did not specify how to in their GitHub repository.

Any help is appreciated!

This is the link for the [GitHub repository for Microsoft's UniLm](https://github.com/microsoft/unilm)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you find this issue on github usefull, you can see if it serves your usecase.
https://github.com/microsoft/unilm/issues/205